# Passing a value from a virtual void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to C#, and having issues with this bit of code in a game I'm developing.

I'm using a script to handle ammo, and I'd like to play a sound when the weapon fires the last round in a clip (M1 Garand). The issue is that the "ammo" variable seems to be static, and is only ever changed inside of a virtual void. I have no idea how to pass the changed value out of the void. I need to somehow detect when I have one shot left in the clip, and send some sort of indicator to the "protected virtual void" for the shot sound effect, and then fire both the shot sound, and the clip eject sound. Here's what I have so far (I'm trying to only paste relevant parts of the code, so forgive me if you're missing some context here):

```
public virtual void UseAmmo(int count =1)
        {
            if (ammo <= 0) return;
            ammo -= count;
            if (ammo <= 0) ammo =0;
        }

protected virtual void ShotEffect()
        {

            onShot.Invoke();

            StopCoroutine(LightOnShoot());

            if (ammo != 1)
            {
                if (source)
                {
                    //source.Stop();
                    source.pitch = (Random.Range(0.9f, 1.1f));
                    source.PlayOneShot(fireClip);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                source.Stop();
                source.PlayOneShot(lastShot);
                source.PlayOneShot(fireClip);
            }

            StartCoroutine(LightOnShoot( 0.037f));
            StartEmitters();
        }
```

Comment: Please share code where you have declare `ammo`.

Comment: It's a public int:

      public int ammo;

Comment: Is `void ShotEffect()` allowed to be changed into `void ShotEffect( out int ammo)`? Set ammo as static is not a ideal. Imagine if player may dual wield guns or having two identical guns in player's inventory.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to use an event.

Inside your UseAmmo function, you need to do a check:

```
public virtual void UseAmmo(int count =1)
        {
            if (ammo <= 0) return;

            //store old ammo
            oldAmmo = ammo;
            ammo -= count;

            //Need to make sure ammo actually changed, and is now down to 1
            if (ammo != oldAmmo && ammo == 1) {
               ClipIsLow();
            }

            if (ammo <= 0) ammo =0;
        }
```

Now you need a `ClipIsLow()` function that fires an event. You can look up events and delegates for more info. You would then have a separate script for your audio that listens for a `clipIsLow` event and then plays the sound.

```
void ClipIsLow() {
    GunEvents.ClipIsLow();
}
```

Then you'd have a GunEvents Class:

```
public static class GunEvents {

   delegate void ClipIsLowEvent();
   public static event ClipIsLowEvent OnClipIsLow;

   //this is how we fire the event
   public static void ClipIsLow(){
       OnClipIsLow?.Invoke();
   }
}
```

then, in your audio script (monobehaviour)

```
void OnEnable() {
   //listen to event, if event occurs call PlayLowClipSound
   GunEvents.OnClipIsLow += PlayLowClipSound;
}

void OnDisable() {
   //Stop listening to event. Important to avoid memory leak.
   GunEvents.OnClipIsLow -= PlayLowClipSound;
}

//Method that is called when event fires. Actually plays the sound.
void PlayLowClipSound() {
   lowClipAudioSource.Play()
}
```

If you don't want to learn events, you could simply add the following inside the same class as your `UseAmmo` method., although this is sure to be bad moving forward since it couples your ammo script to your audio playback, which is never a good idea. Your ammo script shouldn't care what sounds play in your game.

But since you said you're new, here it is anyway.

```
void ClipIsLow() {
    audioSource.Play();
}
```